# Autogenerating SQL script written in SQL as opposed to a function in Python

Tags: python, sql, presto

So I have this giant list of values and I want to create this table on SQL where I select columns that have these specific values (so this ends up being one really long script of `WHERE val` and `OR LIKE` statements.

Right now I have it written up in Python to do this automatically; however, is it possible to do the same thing within a SQL query itself.

```
def list_to_like_query(query_list, table_column):
    statement = ''
    for item in query_list:
        if statement == '':
            statement = "WHERE {column} LIKE '%{item}%'".format(column=table_column, item=item)
        else:
            statement = "{statement} OR {column} LIKE '%{item}%'".format(statement=statement, column=table_column, item=item)
    return statement
```

And then I would call the function to generate the sql script for me

```
sql_filter_statment = list_to_like_query(value_list, 'colA')
```

To make things less verbose say `value_list` consisted of like 5 values

```
value_list = ['Sam', 'Smith', 'John', 'Rachel', 'Christina']
```

So then it would output the following:

```
WHERE
    colA LIKE 'Sam'
    OR coLA LIKE 'Smith'
    OR colA LIKE 'John'
    OR colA LIKE 'Rachel'
    OR colA LIKE 'Christina'
```

But yeah, could this be done dynamically written in SQL itself

**Edit**: Forgot to mention the list that is passed through the `list_to_like_query` method is created from retrieving distinct values from another SQL table

Comment: No in SQL itself ..  SQL is not a procedural language ..  dinamic sql  (as you generated  code) is tipically build server side .by a procedural language  in you case python

Comment: @scaisEdge Hmm, I see. So I guess I should have that be generated on the side and then copied into a SQL script

Comment: Normally  .. server side  .once you have recived  the array content.  you build the sql code string and executed ..  .. then you obatin  the result an show  .. (or send to client for show)

Comment: "the list that is passed through the list_to_like_query method is created from retrieving distinct values from another SQL table" , then it's quite natural to exclude client intervention and to build the qurey at the server side, if your dbms supports it.